# MYSQL | insert a value if it does not exist in the same row in the same table

Tags: mysql

I try to do something like that

```
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | customerID |productID       |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 | 123        | 1              | 
+----+------------+----------------+
|  2 | 123        | 2              | 
+----+------------+----------------+
|  3 | 456        | 2              | 
+----+------------+----------------+
```

A customer can have some products but unique.
Another customer can have the same products but also unique for him

And I try to do this:

```
INSERT INTO FavoriteProducts (customerID, productID)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '123', '1') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT productID FROM FavoriteProducts WHERE customerID = '123'
) LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM FavoriteProducts;

+----+------------+----------------+
| id | customerID |productID       |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 | 123        | 1              | 
+----+------------+----------------+
```

I try again with another prudoctID:

```
INSERT INTO FavoriteProducts (customerID, productID)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '123', '2') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT productID FROM FavoriteProducts WHERE customerID = '123'
) LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM FavoriteProducts;

+----+------------+----------------+
| id | customerID |productID       |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 | 123        | 1              | 
+----+------------+----------------+
```

But is's not working :(

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link the query on `NOT EXISTS` with the outer query (using the product ID too):

```
INSERT INTO FavoriteProducts (customerID, productID)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT '123', '2' AS pID) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT productID 
    FROM FavoriteProducts 
    WHERE customerID = '123' AND productID = tmp.pID
) LIMIT 1;
```

You can also use a `UNIQUE` constraint to solve that:

```
ALTER TABLE FavoriteProducts
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_customer_product UNIQUE (customerID, productID);
```

... by using that [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) you can use a simple `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO FavoriteProducts (customerID, productID) VALUES
  ('123', '4');
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c09430f71216b90e9281984fdd5ba54c)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery, but you must use in the `WHERE` clause the condition for the `productID` also:

```
INSERT INTO FavoriteProducts (customerID, productID)
SELECT '123', '1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT productID 
    FROM FavoriteProducts 
    WHERE customerID = '123' AND productID = '1'
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=31ac6f81281837b74e52e501a3f88d87).
The subquery would be useful so you don't need to repeat the values that you want to insert in the `NOT EXISTS` query like this:

```
INSERT INTO FavoriteProducts (customerID, productID)
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT '123' customerID, '1' productID) t  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT productID 
    FROM FavoriteProducts 
    WHERE customerID = t.customerID AND productID = t.productID
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f2642f1ea79e4704d04a31dc7a8b4e8b).

Comment: You don't even need this. You just need properly defined constraints.